# Highchart - tooltip for legends

Tags: charts, highcharts

I am using highcharts to represent data. In my chart based on conditions some series are disabled.

Is there any way to remove the legend `itemhoverstyle` property for disabled series?

Is there any way to add a tooltip to the legend items?

Comment: Are you using a wrapper framework(Like in java) or javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **remove** the serie **from the legend**:

```
series:[{
    name: 'serie1',
    type: 'line',
    data: yourArrayOfData,
    showInLegend: false
}]
```

If you want to change the css on hovering you'll have to change this highcharts-legend style.

To add a tooltip to the legend do something like the following example:
**[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/PtYtf/)**