# HighChart Tooltip Position can be changed?

Tags: highcharts

I am new to highcharts. The Highchart by default displays the tooltip inside the chart itself. Is this possible to display the tooltip outside the chart and in the same position as it used to display inside.Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own div and then use tooltip formatter to display info inside it.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqq9D/

```
tooltip: {
        formatter:function(){
            $('#tooltip').html('Point Y: '+this.y);
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can change it using Tooltip.positioner, here is the link to the API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip

Comment: Tooltip positioner works only in plotChart, not "global". So if you would like to display tooltip outside the chart then it will not work.

Comment: Any example where the chart shows the tooltip outside the chart. thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Default tooltip and custom tooltip at the same time](http://jsfiddle.net/VVFyf/)

Above is an example where you can show both the default tooltip and your own custom tooltip. Credit goes to @Ricardo Lohmann as he showed how to create custom tooltip in the following post:

> [Highchart - tooltip for legends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225896/highchart-tolltip-for-legends)

```
// first of all we've to build a group to put the elements
this.SVGElements = this.chartVar.renderer.g().attr({'zIndex': 11}).add();

// build tooltip text
var textContainer = this.chartVar.renderer.text(text, coord[0], coord[1])
                .attr({
                    'zIndex': 10
                })
                .add(this.SVGElements);

// get text 'box'
var box = textContainer.getBBox();

// build  tooltip square according to the text location, then place the container behind the text
this.chartVar.renderer.rect(box.x - 5, box.y - 5, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 5)
                .attr({
                    'stroke-width': 2,            // border width
                    'stroke': '#a8a8a8',        // border color
                    'zIndex': 9,
                    'fill': 'white',            // background color
                    'fill-opacity': 0.85,        // background opacity
                    'isShadow': true
                })
                .add(this.SVGElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tooltip: {
              positioner: function () {
                    return { x: 45, y: 60 };
                }
            }
```

Use this

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Comment: Is it possible give co-ordinates relative to chart position.? Let's say positioning the  tooltip near top right corner of chart.