# How to display tooltips or legends on plotBands?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

I would like to have tooltips or legends on the gauge bands. I draw the bands like these:

```
plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 10,
                color: '#55BF3B'
            }, {
                from: 10,
                to: 20,
                color: '#DDDF0D'
            }]
```

I would like to see tooltips on mouseover on the bands.

Or the other solution I would like to have is showing legends for each band with the regarding color. There is the option for legends for points but not for bands.

Is there any option like `showInLegend:true` for plotBands? Or any other solution to get these?

Comment: Try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225896/highchart-tolltip-for-legends

Comment: @Pandian that is not what I would like to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general plotBands doesn't have any tooltip or legend options, however it is possible to add some custom events to plotBand, for example mouseover. See: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands.events

So you can create your own tooltip for this.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What would you suggest for adding the bands with color and label into the legends?

Comment: Probably the only two options are to use just area series with fixed min/max or fake series legend (without points) and manage legendItemClick to hide plotBand by removing it.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's *(for instance)* not possible, you can place a `subtitle` below the chart (in my case, a gauge). For example:

```
subtitle: {
    text: '<span style="background-color: #55BF3B; border-radius: 2px; padding: 1px 2px;">' +
              '0-10' +
          '</span>' +
          '<span style="background-color: #DDDF0D; border-radius: 2px; padding: 1px 2px;">' +
              '10-20' +
          '</span>',
    useHTML: true,
    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to make quite elegant labels for gauge plotbands by attaching text to the svg path elements that are generated by Highcharts. By doing this, you can get text that actually follows the curve of the plotband. Specifically look at the code in the annonymous function that triggers after the gauge has initialised. You'll need to get the correct plotband object, assign an id attribute to the path element and then insert text and textPath elements (using createElementNS). You then link the newly-created textPath element using the xlink namespace. In my example I am applying labels for quartiles that are displayed as plotbands around the gauge.

Example:

```
 $(selector).highcharts({
             chart: {
                 type: 'gauge',
                 plotBackgroundColor: null,
                 plotBackgroundImage: null,
                 plotBorderWidth: 0,
                 plotShadow: false
             },
             title: {
                 //oConfig is my own config object
                 text: oConfig.TITLE,
                 style: {"color": "#333333", "fontSize": fontSize, "font-family": "Arial", "font-weight": "bold"}
             },
             pane: {
                 size: "100%",
                 startAngle: -150,
                 endAngle: 150,
                 background: [{
                     backgroundColor: '#FFF',
                     borderWidth: 0,
                     outerRadius: '100%',
                     innerRadius: '100%'
                 }]
             },
             /*the value axis*/
             yAxis: [{
                 min: oConfig.MIN,
                 max: oConfig.MAX,
                 minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                 minorTickWidth: 0,
                 minorTickLength: 10,
                 minorTickPosition: 'inside',
                 minorTickColor: '#666',
                 tickPixelInterval: 30,
                 tickWidth: 2,
                 tickPosition: 'inside',
                 tickLength: 10,
                 tickColor: '#666',
                 labels: {
                     step: 2,
                     rotation: 'auto'
                 },
                 title: {
                     text: null
                 },
                 plotBands: [{
                     from: oConfig.PB1FROM,
                     to: oConfig.PB1TO,
                     color: 'red',
                     outerRadius: "105%",
                     //innerRadius: "10%",
                     thickness : "5%"
                 }, {
                     from: oConfig.PB2FROM,
                     to: oConfig.PB2TO,
                     color: '#fdd01b',
                     outerRadius: "105%",
                     //innerRadius: "10%",
                     thickness : "5%"
                 }, {
                     from: oConfig.PB3FROM,
                     to: oConfig.PB3TO,
                     color: 'green',
                     outerRadius: "105%",
                     //innerRadius: "10%",
                     thickness : "5%"
                 }]
             }],
               credits: {
                    enabled: false
               },
             series: [{
                 name: name,
                 data: []/*,
                 tooltip: {
                      valuePrefix: 'Score: ',
                     valueSuffix: ' out of 5'
                 }*/
             }]
         },
         //Add some life
         function (chart) {
            var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
            var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
            //I create a random id using my own helpers.makeid() method - you'll need to roll your own
            var id = helpers.makeid();

            //quartile 1
            var elem = chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[1].svgElem.element;
            elem.setAttribute("id", id);
            var newText = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-family","Verdana");   
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-weight","bold");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-size","10");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"dy","-5");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","red");
            var newTextPath = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "textPath");
            newTextPath.setAttributeNS(null,"startOffset","10%");
            newTextPath.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, "xlink:href", "#"+id);
            var textNode = document.createTextNode("Quartile 1 (0% to 25%)");
            newTextPath.appendChild(textNode);
            newText.appendChild(newTextPath);
            elem.parentNode.insertBefore(newText, elem.nextSibling);

            //interquartile range (middle 50)
            var elem2 = chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[2].svgElem.element;
            id = helpers.makeid();
            elem2.setAttribute("id", id);
            var newText = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-family","Verdana");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-weight","bold");  
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-size","10");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"dy","-5");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","#fdd01b");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"x", 5);
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"y", 5);
            var newTextPath = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "textPath");
            newTextPath.setAttributeNS(null,"startOffset","10%");
            newTextPath.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, "xlink:href", "#"+id);
            var textNode = document.createTextNode("Middle 50 (25% to 75%)");
            newTextPath.appendChild(textNode);
            newText.appendChild(newTextPath);
            elem.parentNode.insertBefore(newText, elem.nextSibling);

            //quartile 3
            var elem3 = chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[3].svgElem.element;
            id = helpers.makeid();
            elem3.setAttribute("id", id);
            var newText = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-family","Verdana");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-weight","bold");  
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"font-size","10");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"dy","-5");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","green");
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"x", 5);
            newText.setAttributeNS(null,"y", 5);
            var newTextPath = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "textPath");
            newTextPath.setAttributeNS(null,"startOffset","10%");
            newTextPath.setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, "xlink:href", "#"+id);
            var textNode = document.createTextNode("Quartile 3 (75% to 100%)");
            newTextPath.appendChild(textNode);
            newText.appendChild(newTextPath);
            elem.parentNode.insertBefore(newText, elem.nextSibling);
        });
```